# Dirac Delta and expectation value of position

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, dirac-delta

So my lecture posed and integral of the form:

$$\langle x\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi^*(y)\delta(y-x)\psi(y) \, dy = \psi^(x) \psi(x)$$

and then looked at the equation and said have I gone wrong here, so before he could figure out if he was incorrect the lecture was over and posed it as a problem for the class.

Now I am not sure if he is wrong/right but I am under the assumption at the moment that this is correct and if  but what I can understand is how $\psi(x)\psi^*(x)$ can transform to $\psi(y)\psi^*(y)$

My working are as follows:

As the dirac delta $$\int _{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x-y) \, dx=1 \tag{1}$$
then

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(y-x) \, dy=1\tag{[2]}$$

then $(1)=(2).$

$$\int _{-\infty }^\infty \delta(x-y) \, dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(y-x) \, dy$$

but after this I just cant see how the functions match each other and to be honest I can see why the Dirac delta function has been used, I have tried looking for question to get an idea on what the is applied to but so far I have come up trumps. If possible could someone please explain, how and why the relationship comes about.

Comment: Seems like you're invoking the Dirac Delta parity: $\delta(x) = \delta (-x)$

Comment: Note that the quantity your instructor wrote down isn't the expectation value of $x$ (which is normally written as $\langle x \rangle$), but is instead the probability density of finding the particle at $x$.  The quantity $\langle x \rangle$ would be $$\langle x \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \psi^*(x) \psi(x) \, dx.$$

Comment: Note that proper notation is $\langle x\rangle = \cdots,$ not $<x> = \cdots.$ Also one normally puts a small space before $dx$ or $dy,$ as in my edits to the question. I also used \tag{}. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dirac delta "function" works as an identity operation so that 
$$f(x)=\int_a^b\delta(x-y)f(y)\,dy$$
so in some kind of way it can be compared to the identity matrix.

In your case $f(x)=\psi(x)\psi^*(x)$ and $f(y)=\psi(y)\psi^*(y)$.

What may be helpful to you is that the dirac delta "function" has very interesting properties one of which is symmetry so that $\delta(x)=\delta(-x)$ or $$\delta(y-x)=\delta(-[y-x])=\delta(x-y)$$

Thats why you would get $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\delta(x-y) \, dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\delta(y-x) \, dx $$

Then you can just change the name of the variables.